# iterate two arrays and perform AND / OR comparison = return true

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Here is my current filter function (quite incomplete)

```
    $('input:checkbox.types').click(function(){
        filterMarkers();
    });


function filterMarkers() {
    var checked = [];
    $('input:checkbox.types:checked').each(function(){
        checked.push($(this).val());
    });
    checked.sort();
    var andor = '';
    var andor = $('[name="and-or"]:checked').val();
    if(andor == 1) {
        // and
        console.log(checked);
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var types = markers[i]['types'].split(",");
            types.sort();
            console.log(types);
        }
    } else {
        // or

    }

}
```

Here is an image of what I have so far.

http://snag.gy/rKSTA.jpg

Let us say this for simplicity.
A = checked checkboxes
B = array with values of current item in map marker iteration / current iteration marker

I was able to get the values of the checked checkboxes. I was also able to convert the comma delimited string of each marker into an array. I would like to be able to check if B contains ANY of A (OR) and be able to check that B must contain A (AND).

Any ideas?

Here is the page in question for those wanting a 'feel' for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

https://www.cablework.co/company

This page outputs what I have currently to console.

Once I can figure this out, I will then be able to hide/show markers based on the result.

Comment: Looks like you're using JQuery. The JQuery library has a function called `$.inArray(value, array)`. You could use this while iterating to check.

Comment: So you want the function to return an array that represents which markers passed the test right? edit: or no, you just want to do something if the test fails/passes for each marker.

Comment: if boxes 1 and 4 are checked, when going over the markers 'types' array, for my "AND" statement, the markers iteration MUST contain the checked which will result in true ( like is marker array is [1,4,5,7] it is true because it contains ALL of the checked), for my "OR" statement, if the marker contains 1 or 4 then true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example function. You would run `test` on every marker against the types array.

http://jsfiddle.net/q1k6e74d/5/

```
function test(op,types,marker){
    var pass;
    if(types.length === 0 || marker.length === 0){
        return false;
    }
    if(op==="and"){
        pass = true;
        for(var i in types){
            if( $.inArray(types[i],marker) == -1 ){
                pass = false;
            }
        }
    }else{ //or
        pass = false;
        for(var i in marker){
            if( $.inArray(marker[i],types) !== -1 ){
                pass = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return pass;
}

var a = [1,4];
var b = [1,5];
console.log("test a",a,"and b",b,test("and",a,b));
console.log("test a",a,"or b",b,test("or",a,b));
```

Could be shorter but it's easiest to understand this way I think.

Comment: something might be wrong. tried 1,4 for b so a and b are [1,4] with and operator, should return true, it returns false.

Comment: this should return true - http://jsfiddle.net/Kryptonit3/q1k6e74d/4/ - because 1 AND 4 are inside of [1,4,6,7] yet it returns false.

Comment: might be because i have it backwards. changed b and a around in test function. appears to work. Now, how would you write this 'shorter'? @slicedtoad

Comment: @JesseSzypulski For "and", The marker must be all of the boxes? or the marker must be only the boxes?

Comment: your code is working. currently testing different scenarios. will report back. :)

Comment: @JesseSzypulski Actually, the "and" condition is wrong. The function should be called as `test("and",typearray,markerarray)`. It doesn't make a difference for "or".  EDIT: there, I've changed it.